# Sitecore IsPageEditor and IsExperienceEditor

Tags: sitecore, compatibility, sitecore8

We are currently writing a module for Sitecore and have ran into a problem.

We have a pipeline in which we do the following check:

```cs
if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor)
{
     return;
}
```

The problem is that one of our clients are running and older version of Sitecore (8.0 update 5) where the property IsExperienceEditor does not exist yet. See Sitecore [release notes](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/8%200/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2080%20Update6/Release%20Notes) for next update where it is introduced.

To quickly fix the error we used the older deprecated property which is this:

```cs
if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor)
{
     return;
}
```

Now the question is, is there any way in which we can test for the Sitecore version so we can have backwards compatibility in the module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the code which is executed in Sitecore in background of both properties mentioned by you:

```cs
if (Sitecore.Context.Site.DisplayMode == Sitecore.Sites.DisplayMode.Edit)
{
    return;
}
```

I know that using `Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor` (or `Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor`) is more elegant, but in a situation when you need to support both old and new Sitecore versions, that's sounds like a good option.

Answer (score 0):

The deprecated property of `IsPageEditor` is still present specifically for the purpose of backward compatibility. `IsExperienceEditor` is just a renamed property that does the same thing that `IsPageEditor` does.

However you can check for the existence of a property like this:

```
public static bool HasProperty(this object obj, string propertyName)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName) != null;
}
```

Another option is to make two different versions of the module, if the implementation becomes significantly different for the different versions of Sitecore.